# Laravel Controller - Check if parameter passed to method inside controller is a Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Basically, all i want to do is check if the object passed to the method is a model. Doesn't matter what the model is, I just want to make sure its a model. So i tried typecasting the $resource variable/parameter with `Model $resource` however this returned an error.

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Handlers\FileUploadHandler::replaceFile() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Handlers\Model, instance of App\Models\Resource\Ingredient given, called in E:\Sites\kara\app\Http\Controllers\Resources\IngredientsController.php on line 109

Here is my method:

```
// Handle File Replacement
    public static function replaceFile( $resource, Request $request, $storageFolder = 'noPath', $formName = 'fileUpload') {
        // Delete the old file
        Storage::delete($resource->fullPath);
        // Place the new file
        return self::uploadFile($request, $storageFolder, $formName);
    }
```

Here is how i'm calling it:

```
        // Create the object
        $ingredient = Ingredient::where('id', $id)->first();
            $file = FileUploadHandler::replaceFile($ingredient, $request, 'ingredients');
```

Comment: namespacing ... you have to alias `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` if you want to reference it as `Model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

You have to add the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class in your use statements.

So when you call `Model $resource` it will return ok.

Answer (score 0):

To check if some variable is pointing to a `Model` you can use `instanceof`.

Example:

```
<?php
class A{};
class B extends A{};
$obj = new B();

if ($obj instanceof A) {
   echo 'yes';
}
```

Output: `yes`